# Cannot pass value from cgi script back to html form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form with a date field named `cdt`.

I am putting some values into an oracle table through that form using a CGI script. I want to come back to the HTML form and the date field should be retained.

I can easily do that by using the following javascript code in the CGI script.

```
print "history.go(-1)";
```

**However I want to use `window.location.href` instead due to certain reasons.** 
I am trying the following in the CGI script but it is not working.

```
$vdt=$in{cdt};
print "<script type='text/javascript'>";
print "var dtvar = $vdt";
print " window.location.href = '../htdocs/formname.html?cdt=' + dtvar";
print "</script>";
```

Comment: If your JavaScript doesn't work, then show us your JavaScript. Don't show us Perl that generates the JavaScript with data that you aren't sharing with us.

Comment: … and if you want to redirect the browser, then just issue an HTTP `Location` header. Don't generate an HTML document with embedded JS to do it. That's massively overcomplicating matters.

Comment: That's all the javascript I used (embedded in my perl script). Can you please illustrate how it can be done using the HTTP location  header?

Comment: That is not all the JavaScript you used. We have no idea what `$vdt` contains. Even if that wasn't the case, it is much easier to debug JavaScript when we can see the JavaScript as opposed to when we have to work out what the JavaScript is based on running Perl in our heads!

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER

Comment: Also, when your JS doesn't work: Look at your browser's JavaScript error console, it can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print `;` or '\n' between the Javascript statements:

```
vdt=$in{cdt};
print "<script type='text/javascript'>";
print "var dtvar = $vdt;";
print "window.location.href = '../htdocs/formname.html?cdt=' + dtvar;";
print "</script>";
```

If `$in{cdt}` is a string, the assignment should be:

```
print "var dtvar = '$vdt';"
```

Comment: Yeah , Thanx .I missed out on that.but strangely It's still not working. It is getting stuck in the cgi script. If I remove the date field parameter(cdt) it hits the form .

Comment: What is the value of `$in{cdt}`? If it's a string, you need to put quotes around it in the `var dtvar` assignment.

Comment: its a date value from html form. I used the quotes but now it is coming back to my html form but NOT passing the value. Its empty.